# Real line in inequalities solution

Tags: tikz-pgf

In solving one variable linear inequalities I want to show the number line. How to draw real line like this?

[image: inequalities solution]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a MWE which does most of what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=1cm]
  \coordinate (A/l) at (-4,0);
  \coordinate (A/r) at (6,0);

  \coordinate (A/lt/6/l)  at ($(-4,0)+(0,2)$);
  \coordinate (A/lt/6/r)  at ($(6,0)+(0,2)$);

  \coordinate (A/gt/-4/l)  at ($(-4,0)+(0,1)$);
  \coordinate (A/gt/-4/r)  at ($(6,0)+(0,1)$);

  \foreach 
    \pt 
    in 
    {A,A/lt/6,A/gt/-4} 
    { 
      \draw ($(\pt/l)-(2em,0)$) -- ($(\pt/r)+(2em,0)$);
    } 

  %% create and draw end points for each level of graph
  \node[draw,fill,inner sep=4pt,circle] (A/lt/6/n)  at (A/lt/6/r) {};
  \node[draw,inner sep=4pt,circle]      (A/gt/-4/n) at (A/gt/-4/l) {};
  %%
  \node[draw,fill,inner sep=4pt,circle] (A/r/n)  at (A/r) {};
  \node[draw,inner sep=4pt,circle]      (A/l/n)  at (A/l) {};

  %% draw horizontal lines for each level of graph
  \draw[line width=4pt,arrows=->]       (A/lt/6/n) --  ($(A/lt/6/l)-(2em,0)$);
  \draw[line width=4pt,arrows=->]       (A/gt/-4/n) -- ($(A/gt/-4/r)+(2em,0)$);
  \draw[line width=4pt]                 (A/r/n)    -- (A/l/n);
  %% draw vertical lines
  \draw[dashed] ($(A/lt/6/l)+(0,3ex)$) -- ($(A/l)-(0,5ex)$);
  \draw[dashed] ($(A/lt/6/r)+(0,3ex)$) -- ($(A/r)-(0,5ex)$);

  \node at ($(A/lt/6/n)+(-60:3ex)$) {$6$};  
  \node at ($(A/r/n)+(-60:3ex)$)    {$6$};  

  \node at ($(A/gt/-4/n)+(-140:4ex)$) {$-4$};
  \node at ($(A/l/n)+(-140:4ex)$)     {$-4$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is a  solution using Tikz and using conditions in the tikz style (so you can position the circles where you want, from 0 (start) to .5 (half) to 1 (end).

The commands are **empty/full** depending on the type of circle you want to show.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    thickest/.style={line width=3pt},
    empty/.style={decoration={markings,
    mark=at position #1 with {\fill[white,draw=black,thin] circle (3pt);}},postaction={decorate}},
    full/.style={decoration={markings,
    mark=at position #1 with {\fill circle (3pt);}},postaction={decorate}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3mm,y=1.2em]
       \draw (-4,0) -- (6,0);
       \draw (-8,2) -- (10,2);
       \draw (-8,4) -- (10,4);

       \draw[dashed] (-4,-1) -- (-4,6);
       \draw[dashed] (6,-1) -- (6,6);

       \node[anchor=north east] at (-4,0) {-4};
       \node[anchor=north west] at (6,0) {6};
       \node[anchor=north east] at (-4,2) {-4};
       \node[anchor=north west] at (6,4) {6};

% ARROWS

\draw[thickest,empty=0,full=1] (-4,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thickest,empty=0,-stealth] (-4,2) -- (10,2);
\draw[thickest,full=0,-stealth] (6,4) -- (-8,4);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @kalakay: Please upvote answers that you find helpful (by clicking the button above the vote count next to the answer), and if you consider your question answered, mark the most helpful answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I do not know about this.

Answer (score 3):

With PSTricks just for fun as usual. I think the numbers should not be repeated to save more keystrokes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(7,4)
    \psset{linewidth=.5\pslinewidth,linestyle=dashed}
    \psline(2,.5)(2,3.5)
    \psline(5,.5)(5,3.5)
    \uput[d](2,.5){$-4$}
    \uput[d](5,.5){$6$}
    \psset{linewidth=5\pslinewidth,linestyle=solid}
    \psline{o-*}(2,1)(5,1)
    \psline{o->}(2,2)(6,2)
    \psline{<-*}(1,3)(5,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to align the baseline of each label with the same line then use `\rput` instead of `\uput`.