# mark interval over the line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I need make a picture like this, make a function interval over the line:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. Anyone know?

Comment: No you don't need to make that picture. You can surely do better than that. One example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138943/real-line-in-inequalities-solution

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyon

Answer (score 8):

Following the comments above and the link,

[Real line in inequalities solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138943/real-line-in-inequalities-solution)

I made this

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    thickest/.style={line width=3pt},
    empty/.style={decoration={markings,
    mark=at position #1 with {\fill[white,draw=black,thin] circle (3pt);}},postaction={decorate}},
    full/.style={decoration={markings,

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=1.2em]
       \draw (  5,0) -- (11,0);
       \draw ( -5,2) -- (13,2);
       \draw ( -5,4) -- (13,4);

       \draw[dashed] ( 10,-1) -- ( 10,6);
       \draw[dashed] (  5,-1) -- (  5,6);

       \node[anchor=north east] at ( 5,0) {$-1+\sqrt{3}$};
       \node[anchor=north west] at (10,0) {$ 1+\sqrt{3}$};

       \node[anchor=north east] at ( 1,2) {$ 1-\sqrt{3}$};
       \node[anchor=north west] at (10,2) {$ 1+\sqrt{3}$};
       \node[anchor=north] at (4,2) {$ < 0 $};


       \node[anchor=south] at ( 5,4) {$-1+\sqrt{3}$};
       \node[anchor=south] at (-1,4) {$ 1-\sqrt{3}$};
       \node[anchor=north] at (-3,4) {$ > 0 $};
       \node[anchor=north] at ( 8,4) {$ > 0 $};

       \node[anchor=west] at ( 13,4) { Equação 1};
       \node[anchor=west] at ( 13,2) { Equação 2};

       %\node[anchor=north west] at ( 6,4) {6};

% ARROWS

\draw[thickest,full=0,full=1] ( 5,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[thickest,full=0,full=1] (10,2) -- ( 1,2);
\draw[thickest,full=0,-stealth] (-1,4) -- (-5,4);
\draw[thickest,full=0,-stealth] ( 5,4) -- (13,4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

this was the result,

[image]

thanks by your help.

Comment: Much better indeed :)